# MySQL multiple Inner Join with Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

i have a little problem with mysql. query is follow:

```
SELECT u.user_id,u.gender, ua.age,u.name,u.isonline,dot.profile_image_no FROM user_table AS u
INNER JOIN user_answers_table AS ua ON u.user_id = ua.user_id
INNER JOIN data_one_table AS dot ON dot.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN user_detail_table AS udt ON udt.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.isregistrationcomplete='1' AND u.isactive='1' AND u.gender = '0' AND ua.age >= '20' AND ua.age <= '24' AND udt.lookingfor = '1' OR udt.lookingfor = '3';
```

i want to get only u.gender = '0' users but that query return to me with u.gender = '1' so where is the problem?

query result:

```
user_id  gender     age  name         isonline  profile_image_no  
-------  ------  ------  -----------  --------  ------------------
    62       0      29  Wqasaasd            1                   1
    93       1      28  Sadasda             1                   1
    131       0      26  Wedsas              1                   1
    155       0      91  Wwsfwdf             1                   1
    173       0      23  Yirmi30             1                   1
    220       0      20  Fjalekalimi         1                   1
    232       0      20  Seeemani            1                   1
    236       0      21  Mesut               1                   1
    238       0      89  23wdsca             1                   1
    247       0      23  11eqwe              1                   1
    252       0      24  Workhard            1                   1
    253       0      25  Sdsdg               1                   1
    343       1      25  Emily               1                   1
```

Answer (score 4):

Stick your `OR` inside a bracket and try again!

```
SELECT u.user_id,u.gender, ua.age,u.name,u.isonline,dot.profile_image_no FROM user_table AS u
INNER JOIN user_answers_table AS ua ON u.user_id = ua.user_id
INNER JOIN data_one_table AS dot ON dot.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN user_detail_table AS udt ON udt.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.isregistrationcomplete='1' 
AND u.isactive='1' 
AND u.gender = '0' 
AND ua.age >= '20' 
AND ua.age <= '24' 
AND (udt.lookingfor = '1' OR udt.lookingfor = '3');
```

Answer (score 2):

Bad logical syntax:

```
AND (udt.lookingfor = '1' OR udt.lookingfor = '3');
```